# Nginx config for 2 PHP applications with url prefixes

Tags: php, symfony, nginx

I would like to serve 2 PHP(Symfony) applications under the same domain, with a URL prefix for one of the apps.
So www.mydomain.com/ should serve the first app while www.mydomain.com/secondapp should serve the second one.
I ended up with this config which doesn't work :

```
server {
    server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;

    location / {
        root /var/www/first-app/web;
        try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location /secondapp {
        root /var/www/second-app/web;
        try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/(app|app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
    }
}
```

When I put the root directive for the first app under the last location, it works for the first app but the second can't be served.
Should I create a second server directive and use sub-domain rewriting instead?

Thanks!

Comment: what happens in the second server? does it show error? ( php error? or symfony error from first app? )  or downloads the php file?

Comment: For the second app I get a 404 error from symfony (it requests /secondapp whereas I would like it to request /, I think I need URL rewriting).

Answer (score 1):

You should use alias instead of root in your locations. If you use root, the path that is matched in the location is added to the root path.

Answer (score 0):

So I finally found the solution: my nginx conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.mydomain.com;
    root /var/www/first-app/web;

    location ~ ^/secondapp(/.*)$ {
        alias /var/www/second-app/web;
        try_files $1 @app;
    }

    location @app {
        expires off;
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/second-app/web/app.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME     /secondapp/app.php;
        fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI     /secondapp$1;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/(app|app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/app_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/app_access.log;
}
```